# Use Directory.Move with Spaces in C#, when Filepath is created from multiple List entries, which are generated by DirectoryInfo

Tags: c#, directory-structure

I made a WPF-Tool to read all Directories in a User specified Directory, then to scan if there are Any similarities within those names, and create new Directories according to those similarities. But to replace any Dots with Spaces and move every Directory with this similarity into the new Folder. When trying this without the Dot-Removal it works fantastic, but when using it with Spaces it always throws the error Directory Path not found.

Example:

```
The directories

usrpath\A.B.C.D.E.F.X
usrpath\A.B.C.D.E.F.Y
usrpath\A.B.C.D.E.F.z

should result in: 

usrpath\A B C D E F\A.B.C.D.E.F.X
usrpath\A B C D E F\A.B.C.D.E.F.Y
usrpath\A B C D E F\A.B.C.D.E.F.Z



        Directory.Move(fulldir[i], System.IO.Path.Combine(usrpath , System.IO.Path.Combine(founddirspace[i2], dirname[i]))
    
    usrpath = Folderpath given by user
    fulldir[i] = Original directory path
    founddirspace[i] = List with all found similarities with dots replaced
    dirname[i] = Original name of the directory without path
```

The Above used Strings are all stored in separated String Lists and are automatically generated:

```
    foreach (var d in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(usrpath))
                    {
                        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(d);
                        var dirName = dir.Name;
                        dirname.Add(dirName);
                        fulldir.Add(d);
                    }

int g = i - (dirname[counter].Substring(0, i).LastIndexOf(Trennzeichen));
    if (g > 0){
     if (g == 1){
        if (dirname[counter].Substring(0,i-g).Length < 4){
         counter++;
         break;
        }
    else{
     compare = dirname[counter].Substring(0, i - g);
     founddir.Add(compare);
     founddirspace.Add(compare.Replace(Trennzeichen, " "));
    }
  }




foreach (var item in founddirspace)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(System.IO.Path.Combine(usrpath, item)) ;
                multserienfullpath.Add(System.IO.Path.Combine(usrpath, item));
            }
```

The New Folder with spaces gets created, when outputting the above move command in a Message-box the Syntax is correct, when checking each folder individually with Directory.Exists it also confirms, that each directory exists but when trying to execute the actual move command it always throws the error. When Defining the exact same path manually the Move command works. So it most likely has something to do with the spaces or is caused by some syntax error.

I already tried to append an @"" and @ to the Command and to the different List variables but I just can't get it to work properly.

Comment: The best description of your code is the code itself not a list of what the variables are supposed to be. Please show the code that initializes those variables and the code that leads to that failing line

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood your problem seems to be that the new parent folder with the spaces: `/usrpath/A B C D E F` simply isn't created, so you cant move something into.

If I understood your general scenario correctly, you have a bunch of subfolders - all contained in the same parent folder - and you want to move these subfolders into a new parentfolder, that needs to be created.
The name and path of the new parent folder has something to do with substring simliarities/equalities in these subfolder names - this algorithm works, the common substring is known.

If that is true you, could do it as in the code below. Works at least on my machine (using windows path syntax like "C:\Folder...", but System.IO can handle UNIX Path conventions...)

```
    string[] directoryPaths = { 
                                 "/usrPath/A.B.C.D.E.F.X",
                                 "/usrPath/A.B.C.D.E.F.Y",
                                 "/usrPath/A.B.C.D.E.F.z"
                              };

    var commonNamePart = "A.B.C.D.E.F";
    var commonNamePartSpaced = commonNamePart.Replace('.', ' ');

    var newDirectoryPaths = directoryPaths.Select( p => {
                    var pa = Path.GetDirectoryName(p);
                    var na = Path.GetFileName(p);
                    return Path.Combine(pa, commonNamePartSpaced, na);
            }).ToArray();

    var newParentPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(newDirectoryPaths[0]);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(newParentPath);
    for (var i = 0; i < newDirectoryPaths.Length; i++) {
            Directory.Move(directoryPaths[i], newDirectoryPaths[i]);
    }
```

Comment: The creation of the Parentfolder works flawlessly with Spaces or with dots, the Movement of the "old" Folders into the new Parentfolder with Dots works too but when the Dots are replaced by spaces It throws the Error

Comment: But System.IO classes and methods in general can handle space without problems and just the same way as paths without spaces. Paths with spaces are an issue on the commandline aka "Shell", where they need to be quoted, but not here. Since you are using UNIX syntax for the paths - what kind of device and OS is it? Does it allow folders with spaces to be created?

Comment: I use windows, and the program is intended to only run on windows. And yes, it allows folders with spaces to be created, i have the entered Userpath open in the explorer to view the changes the program makes. And it always creates the folder correctly

Comment: Okay, so in your real code, you are using path naming conventions like "D:\MyFolder\MySub Folder\file.txt". With backslashes as separator, not slashes.

Comment: It's hard to help, since the error is likely hidden in the logic of your code, which is just partially available for us SO users...

Comment: Yes, i assume the error gets thrown, because there are no quotes in the strings itself, but cant figure out how to add them, without getting an illegal character error

Comment: *but when the Dots are replaced by spaces It throws the Error* => then the code that builds the destination path for Directory.Move doesn't build the path you want or a part of that path doesn't exist.

Comment: Missing quotes are likely not the problem. You don't need quotes in Directory.Move or Directory.CreateDirectory. `Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\New Folder\New subfolder")` is valid

Comment: I thought that too, and added an Outputwindow to the code, to see the actual content of the strings them self, and what the final assembled result is and there were no errors in the Syntax and path names.

Comment: As already mentioned the paths needs to be syntactically legal (seems true, as you say), also the parent folder structure needs to already exist, and of course the source path must exist.

You could add helper statements before Directory.Move to verify this, like
`Debug.Assert(Directory.Exists(sourceFolderPath));`
`Debug.Assert(Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(destinationFolderPath)));`

Comment: Thanks, ill try that

Comment: The Debug assert throws no error, but Directory.Move still does. And it definitely has something to do with the spaces

Comment: ok. the only problem with spaces in paths/names I know is that the are not allowed at the beginning/end of a name. Maybe your replacement logic creates such names. `usrpath/A B C D E /a.b.c.d.e` would not be legal and throw an exception. Maybe you need to *`Trim`* the spaced names.

Comment: Nope, there are no spaces at the beginning or at the end. If i check with Directory.exists each Folder individually it always returns true, but when executing Move it throws the error Part of Path not found. So it seems to be some syntax error caused by spaces. if I manually give definitions of the paths like string example = @"D:\some folder with spaces" it works too